# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to install a project using Maven but I get this error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project locanda: /opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
```

I've tried to edit my project folder adding /opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db but the error still appears.

You can read my pom.xml [here](https://github.com/Ema-jar/locanda/blob/master/pom.xml). If I remove the line:

`<db.folder>/opt/h2/databases</db.folder>`

the installation ends with no problems.

This is stack trace for the error, retrieved using clean install -X

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project locanda: /opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) on project locanda: /opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: /opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.MavenFilteringException: /opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.filterResources(DefaultMavenResourcesFiltering.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.resources.ResourcesMojo.execute(ResourcesMojo.java:310)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1107)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1013)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:2234)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.filtering.DefaultMavenFileFilter.copyFile(DefaultMavenFileFilter.java:123)
    ... 29 more
```

The folder of my project can be found [here](https://github.com/Ema-jar/locanda).

Can you show me the cause of the problem? I'm trying to learn Maven and I would really appreciate some help.

P.s.
I'm unsing IntelliJ.

Comment: Try using this `<db.folder>opt/h2/databases</db.folder>`.  I have removed the first forward slash.

Comment: Thank you @RITZXAVI. It works, if you write the answer I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Would be nice to know why the -1. Meh...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `<db.folder>opt/h2/databases</db.folder>`.

I have removed the first forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is searching for the file "/opt/h2/databases/locanda.h2.db" not in the intended area but in the default working directory

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it doesn't help me :-)